# Turn off validation for form type if checkbox is checked in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I'm trying to create an address form with a payment and shipping address. When a checkbox on the shipping address is checked, I want to skip form validation from occurring on that address.

I have created the form type below with a toggle option that will display and deal with the checkbox, however the form is still validated even when checked.

Symfony has [documentation on how to implement such a form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html), and even though I almost have the exact same code, validation is not turned off when checked. I am not using validation groups, so I just disable the default group to disable validation on the entity.

The `AddressType` building a form for the `Address` class (which has annotation constraints on certain fields like `NotBlank` and `Callback`).

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options["toggle"]) {
            $builder->add("toggle", CheckboxType::class, [
                "mapped" => false,
                "required" => false,
                "label" => $options["toggle"]
            ]);
        }

        $builder
            ->add("name", TextType::class, [
                "required" => !$options["toggle"]
            ])
            ->add("address", TextType::class, [
                "required" => !$options["toggle"]
            ])
            ->add("zipcode", TextType::class, [
                "label" => "Postcode",
                "required" => !$options["toggle"]
            ])
            ->add("city", TextType::class, [
                "required" => !$options["toggle"]
            ])
            ->add("countryCode", ChoiceType::class, [
                "choices" => Address::COUNTRY_CODES
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            "toggle" => false,
            "data_class" => Address::class,
            "validation_groups" => function(FormInterface $form) {
                if ($form->has("toggle") && $form->get("toggle")->getData() === true) {
                    return [];
                }

                return ["Default"];
            }
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes("toggle", ["bool", "string"]);
    }
}
```

I use the type like this:

```
$addressForm = $this
    ->createFormBuilder([
        "paymentAddress" => $paymentAddress,
        "shippingAddress" => $shippingAddress
    ])
    ->add("paymentAddress", AddressType::class, [
        "label" => false
    ])
    ->add("shippingAddress", AddressType::class, [
        "label" => false,
        "toggle" => "Use payment address"
    ])
    ->add("submit", SubmitType::class, [
    ])
    ->getForm();
```

I've been going over this for a few hours now but I am not able to deduce why validation is not being turned off, and I am not willing to botch up a form over this little detail.

Why is validation for the `AddressType` not turned off by the closure in configureOptions? If this is just not how it works, what would be a better solution to accomplish partially turning off validation in a tidy way?

EDIT: Even if setting `"validation_groups" => false` in the defaults, in the children created in the builder, or in the usage of the form, validation will still happen. It does not have to do with the closure. Every online resource, including Symfony's own resource states that it should work though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] so I just disable the default group to disable validation on the entity.

Assuming that `Address` properties & constraints look like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $name;

// etc.
```

The "validator" assumes that these properties will be evaluated with `Default` group, because it always considers empty `validation_groups` (e.g.  `return [];`) as `['Default']` (hence validation is not turned off when checked):

> https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html:
> If no groups are specified, all constraints that belong to the group `Default` will be applied.

**A solution to accomplish partially turning off validation in a tidy way**

Should there be many ways to achieve it, but I show you two of them:

1. If none `data_class` is set to the root form, then `Form` group is available to validate this level only:

   ```
   $addressForm = $this
       ->createFormBuilder([...], [
           'validation_groups' => 'Form', // <--- set
       ])
   ```

   Next, in `configureOptions` method, set `Address` group as default and `Form` group if "toggle" is checked, also adds `Valid()` constraint for cascade validation:

   ```
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults([
           // ...
           "validation_groups" => function(FormInterface $form) {
               if ($form->has("toggle") && $form->get("toggle")->getData() === true) {
                   return ['Form']; // <--- set
               }

               return ['Address']; // <--- set
           },
           'constraints' => [new Assert\Valid()], // <--- set
       ]);
   }
   ```

   That means, on submit with toggle off: `Form` and `Address` groups are applied to address fields, else, only `Form` group is applied.
2. (Another way) In `Address` class add "Required" group to all constraints, it avoids validate these properties with `Default` group:

   ```
   /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Required"}) // <--- set
    */
   private $name;

   // etc.
   ```

   Next, in `configureOptions` method set `Required` as default group and `Default` if toggle is checked:

   ```
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults([
           // ...
           "validation_groups" => function(FormInterface $form) {
               if ($form->has("toggle") && $form->get("toggle")->getData() === true) {
                   return ['Default']; // <--- set
               }

               return ['Required']; // <--- set
           },
           'constraints' => [new Assert\Valid()], // <--- set
       ]);
   }
   ```

   In this case, on submit with toggle off: `Default` and `Required` groups are applied to address fields, else only `Default` group, skipping thus the required fields.

Nested forms that contain objects disconnected from the root object can be validated by setting the constraints option to `new Valid()`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I had already tried adding groups to all constraints and by default returning those groups from the validation_groups closure. What was missing for me was the Valid constraint. It didn't occur to me that the added fields would become children of the AddressType and thus needed the constraint.